# My website is down, yet FTP works

Tags: website

For some reason, my website sudhir.in (with or without www) doesn't load in the browser.

Ping shows :

```
~$ ping sudhir.in
PING sudhir.in (209.217.227.45) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from static-45-227-217-209.nocdirect.com (209.217.227.45): icmp_req=1 ttl=45 time=237 ms
```

FTP works as I am able to log in.

AKS INFO is my hosting provider.

I asked them, he said all other sites on the same server and from same domain hosting provider are working. Please check from your end.

I'm not sure what I should be checking for. Any ideas ?

Comment: Restart the web service?

Comment: This is on a shared hosting server. All my other sites on the same server are up fine.

Comment: I guess you or someone else deleted your files (at least index.html or the equivalent), as the server answers with a 404.  Can you see your files at the expected location when you login via FTP?

Comment: Your web server is throwing an HTTP 404. Good bet your web server is not setup correctly.

Check your error logs. See what it says and post the log here.

Comment: There is an index.php file though.

Comment: As this is shared hosting there is probably very little we can do to help - we generally expect people here to be managing their own servers.

Answer (score 1):

Your web server is not down, it just has been defaced. It has probably be hacked or someone of your team delete the font page.

So, just connect to your site via FTP and see what is still here. The index.html file seems to be empty, just copy any backup of your site and it'll be back.

Be carefull you got some security issue on your website which should warn you.

The uri `/cgi-sys/guestbook.cgi` & `/_vti_bin/shtml.exe`looks like weak point to me, look at it very carefully...